# automatic test generation and real-time HIL execution?

Tags: automated-tests, real-time, simulink

I am looking into real-time automated test generation and execution solutions to verify a certain product. I assume some level of formal methods to be applied to achieve such a goal.

I am aware of the new release of Simulink Test, and from my understanding, such environment allows automated execution, but not automated generation of test cases i.e. the user needs to use Simulink Test GUI to create a series of test cases which can be then ran automatically.

I am aware of Simulink Design Verifier which allows one instead of selecting a Simulink model and having Test Generation Advisor to auto generate a list of test cases (even though it is not clear to me following what logics they may be created upon) to then import them onto Simulink Test.

Simulink Test is then reported to be compatible with real-time HIL testing. Does it mean it is compatible with Simulink real-time and speedgoat machine?

These conjectures may be confused and imprecise, I am relying on the community to give some light into the feasibility of this.

Answer (score 0):

With Simulink Test, you can create real-time tests for HIL, but you can only execute them on a target computer running Simulink Real-Time
("A new Real-Time Test builds a Simulink® Real-Time™ application from your model or test harness and runs it on a target computer.", mathworks.com/help/sltest/release-notes.html; "When you use Simulink Test with Simulink Real-Time™, test cases for real-time testing can be authored and managed in Simulink Test.", mathworks.com/products/simulink-test/features.html#manage-test-plans-and-test-execution)

The same goes for Speedgoat: if you want to run tests created with Simulink in real-time on Speedgoat, you'll need Simulink Real-Time.

There are other testing tools that can handle Simulink models and run automated real-time tests on hardware, for example Mx-Suite (danlawinc.com/mx-suite/) or TPT (www.piketec.com/en/2/tpt.html). They also need the Simulink Real-Time feature.

The latter, TPT, can also generate test cases from Simulink models with a tool named TASMO (www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9Z5n93bu6o). The difference between TASMO and Design Verifier is that TASMO is a search based mechanism while the Design Verifier uses model checking algorithms for test case generation. Both algorithms have advantages and disadvantages and create different test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simulink Test to manually author tests and then run them in HIL with Speedgoat hardware.  [This documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sltest/ug/test-models-in-real-time-and-assess-results.html) explains the process in detail.

You are correct that Simulink Test does not fully automatically generate tests. You can use Simulink Test to create test iterations to semi-automatically perform sweeps etc.

However, you can use Simulink Design Verifier to automatically generate tests.  Simulink Design Verifier uses formal methods and exhaustively attempts to generate tests to satisfy various criteria (functional requirements, coverage/testability, etc.)  You an do this within Simulink Test.  See [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sltest/ug/create-test-cases-from-simulink-design-verifier-results.html) for additional detail.